# Firebase Crashlytics Console not showing crashes on neither new or old builds anymore

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

i am having an issue with firebase Crashlytics where crashes are not showing up but the crash free rate percentage is.

#### The Problem

One day, on what seemed like a random day, all Crashlytic logs stopped showing up on the Firebase Crashlytics console. The crash free rate percentage, however, does show up there. I assume that they are indeed getting some data, because in order to calculate this crash free percentage they need the crash log data (maybe not, idk).

To add to this, older builds where crashes **used to be seen**, also stopped showing the crash logs in the Firebase Crashlytics console. At this point i am convinced that it might not be a configuration issue on our end, if it was older builds shouldnt be affected.

There are no error logs either, telling us that something is wrong.

#### What i have tried

- Checked to see if we changed anything related to firebase crashlytics (besides updating to the latest version)
- Updating to the latest firebase Crashlytics version (multiple times)
- Ive tried comparing the google-services.json file to the one we have in the project, and it is the same.
- Contacting the firebase team, been at it for a few weeks now and still could not resolve, ive sent the logs, code snippets, everything they asked for. But still no solution.
- Made sure we no longer have any references to the old crashlytics/fabric plugin/implementation.

#### Project info:

```
  - Kotlin version: 1.4.10
  - Gradle plugin version: 4.0.2
  - firebase-crashlytics-gradle version: 2.3.0
  - Firebase Crashlytics version: 17.2.2
```

#### Existing Crashlytics configuration:

Project level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
        classpath group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

App level build.gradle

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

if (project.hasProperty("enableJacoco")) {
    apply from: '../jacoco.gradle'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my-app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29

        testInstrumentationRunner "com.my-app.TestAppJUnitRunner"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        // for auto factory
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath = true
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            debuggable false
            testCoverageEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            FirebasePerformance {
                instrumentationEnabled false
            }
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled project.hasProperty("enableJacoco")

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }

    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'
    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'
}

dependencies {

    // Firebase
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2"
    
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

(cleaned up to show firebase related only)

---

Note: We have our google-services.json located in the proper location in our project, as it always been.

Was hoping someone else would be able to help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Firebase crashlytics (after migration from fabric) , reports of IPs of countries that are under the sanctions of Google are not visible in the console.
This may be someone's problem.

Comment: This is happening for all reports, for all of our users. Not a single report is showin in the console